# Log shipping jobs are not executing

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I have configured log shipping between instances, everything was working fine, but recently I have noticed that time on my secondary server differs from time on primary server. I changed time according to the primary server, but now my copy and restore jobs are not executing. They don`t even give exceptions about failure, they are simply not executing. Could you please advise ?

Comment: A logshipping can work fine with servers in different timezone. Did you changed time to back date?. You changed the time so accordingly the schedule has been adjusted. Can you manually execute the jobs, tell me what happens when you manually execute them

Comment: Yes, thank you I changed the time back to the previous date, now jobs are executing again.

Comment: My guess would be you set the time back to match the primary server? If so, log shipping may not process the data thinking it already has. I haven't dealt with log shipping in awhile, but I seem to remember coming across your scenario in SQL 2005 and coming to that conclusion.